# SBCL sockets: reuse-address

Tags: sockets, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

The call to `sockopt-reuse-address` seems to have no effect.

```
(setf socket (make-instance 'sb-bsd-sockets:inet-socket 
                            :type type :protocol protocol)
(setf (sb-bsd-sockets:sockopt-reuse-address socket) t)
(setf (sb-bsd-sockets:non-blocking-mode socket) t)
(sb-bsd-sockets:socket-bind socket ip port)
(sb-bsd-sockets:socket-listen socket backlog)
```

Attempt to rebind to the same port raises the following error:

```
Socket error in "bind": EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
   [Condition of type SB-BSD-SOCKETS:ADDRESS-IN-USE-ERROR]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I give the bounty for an implementation of SO_REUSEPORT. (Actually this is my first bounty and I just want to see how that works)

Answer (score 2):

You could try out [IOLib](http://common-lisp.net/project/iolib/), whose `make-socket` function seems to support a `:reuse-address` keyword.  As far as I recall, IOLib does not make use of the Lisp implementation's built-in networking functionality, so it might work even without SBCL supporting the feature directly.

I haven't tested it, though.

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=BANLkTimMuTf8YruYATDR-aP9HNfOSSNh1A@mail.gmail.com&forum_name=sbcl-help) at sbcl-help.